# Changes to the Arduino moderation team

Tags: discussion, announcement

It is with great sadness that we have to say goodbye to VE7JRO in the moderator team. We thank him for the sterling work he has done during his tenure as moderator and wish him all the best.

As a result a moderator election will shortly be called. If you think you might be able to fill his shoes, watch this space.

Comment: I see Nick Gammon is active on Arduino SE again.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to take a moment to say thank you to VE7JRO for all the time and effort you've spent on moderating Arduino:SE.  It really is appreciated.

Good luck with whatever you are going to be doing next.